# How do I combine blocks and methods returning values in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, block, objective-c-blocks

I'm new to blocks in iOS, and I'm trying to figure out the correct way to use them. Here's my setup:

I have a method `foo` which returns whether an operation (`RKObjectRequestOperation`) succeeded or not. I provide the operation with a block for success and a block for failure, so in the success block I want `foo` to return YES, and in the failure block I want `foo` to return `NO`.

For example:

```
- (BOOL) foo {
    RKObjectRequestOperation *request = [[RKObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest responseDescriptors:responseDescriptors];

    [request setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        NSLog(@"Success!");
        // return YES?
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation , NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure!");
        // return NO?
    }];

    [request start];
}
```

However, as far as I know, a block is only able to return its own value; it cannot cause the method which is calling it to return. Is this correct? If this is the case, the only thing I can think of is to have `foo` take another block as a parameter which is called on success or on failure of the operation. The problem with this is that going up the call stack from 'foo`, I would have to change any method with a return type to return void and accept a block as a parameter to call instead. It seems excessive to have to change all of those methods. Am I missing something conceptually?

Comment: The `foo` in your example is a method, not a function.

Comment: I end up using NSNotificationCenter to return the value when I'm using block inside a method. Anyone knows if this is allowed or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're missing is the fact that this block is (presumably<sup>1</sup>) called asynchronously. It's a completion block, so it's not fired until the requested operation is complete, which is a concurrent operation. So by the time the block has fired, your `-foo` method has already returned to its caller, and has probably made it all the way back to the runloop and has started doing other stuff.

Basically, this means that you can't return anything from `-foo` based on the block, because the block hasn't fired yet. You'll need to redesign your `-foo` method to be asynchronous itself.

<sup><sup>1</sup>I'm not familiar with `RKObjectRequestOperation` but completion blocks only make sense in an asynchronous context.</sup>

Comment: Right, but then my issue is that I have to redesign `foo`, plus the method that calls `foo`, plus the method that calls that, and so on until I finally hit a method that returns void and doesn't have to worry about returning a value anyway. Is this inherent to introducing asynchronous blocks?

Comment: @ferson2020: That's the nature of asynchronicity. There are ways to introduce synchronous behavior, but they're risky and typically a bad design. One example of riskiness is if the operation that you're waiting on wants to run code on your thread (i.e. if you're on the main thread and it needs to bounce off the main thread for whatever reason), it will deadlock. Not to mention blocking the main thread is a bad idea to begin with.